# LaTeX: index entry changed by makeindex without warning

Tags: indexing, makeindex

I'm having a problem with `makeindex -g`, quoting, and using `Y'`:

I create two index entries like this:

```
\index{Y'@$Y'$|see{Luma}}
\index{Farbmodell!Y'CBCR@$Y'C_BC_R'$|main}
```

(with `\newcommand{\main}[1]{\textbf{#1}}`)

This generates these `.idx` entries:

```
\indexentry{Y'@$Y'$|see{Luma}}{43}
\indexentry{Farbmodell!$'CBCR@$Y'C_BC_R'$|main}{43}
```

To use `-g` (I also use `-r`), I've set up an index style using `quote '\''` (and some more formatting). This seems to mess with having `'` in the index entries, while `makeindex` (version 2.15 [TeX Live 2017] (kpathsea + Thai support)) does not print an error related to it.

The output in `.ind` is:

```
  \item Farbmodell
    \subitem $YC_BC_R$\hspace{1em}\dotfill\hspace{1em}\main{43}
  \item Y@$Y$\hspace{1em}\dotfill\hspace{1em}\see{Luma}{43}
```

So the `'` got lost in the first output, and `Y@` is being displayed for the second.  Unfortunately I have no idea how to fix it (the set of usable quote characters seems quite limited).

I case this matters, here's my document preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{showidx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\input{styledefs}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the quote character to `'`, then you have to quote it when using it in an index entry.

Here's a schematic solution. The `filecontents*` environment is just to make the example self-contained. If the current directory contains a file with the same name as the main TeX file and extension `.mst`, this one will be automatically used by MakeIndex.

### File `main.tex`

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
quote '\''
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\providecommand{\main}[1]{#1} % I don't know what \main should do

\begin{document}

Some text

\index{Y''@$Y''$|see{Luma}}
\index{Farbmodell!Y''CBCR@$Y''C_BC_R''$|main}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

### File `main.idx`

```latex
\indexentry{Y''@$Y''$|see{Luma}}{1}
\indexentry{Farbmodell!Y''CBCR@$Y''C_BC_R''$|main}{1}
```

### File `main.ind` (after running MakeIndex)

```latex
\begin{theindex}

  \item Farbmodell
    \subitem $Y'C_BC_R'$, \main{1}

  \indexspace

  \item $Y'$, \see{Luma}{1}

\end{theindex}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: You find the definition of `|main` below the first code block in the question, but it's irrelevant to the problem anyway.

Comment: I searched my candidates in Emacs using `\\index{[^}]*'[^}]*}`, and it worked perfectly!